# How to Prove a Set of Polynomials is a basis for $\mathbb{P_3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given a set of four polynomials, $\{t-1,t+1,t^2-1,t^3\}$. I let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{P_3}$ such that $$\alpha = \alpha_o+\alpha_1t+\alpha_2t^2+\alpha_3t^3$$ Next I multiplied my basis elements by $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ respectively to get $$dt^3+ct^2+(a+b)t+(b-a)$$ Clearly, we must choose $d=\alpha_3$ and $c=\alpha_2$ however can I just say that $a+b=\alpha_1$ and $b-a=\alpha_o$? It doesn't seem to me that we will be able to generate every component of $\mathbb{P_3}$ but I don't necessarily see why.

Comment: Because you missed the $-1$ part of $t^2-1$. You should get $dt^3+ct^2+(a+b)t+(b-a-c)$.

Comment: Note that by adding and subtracting the first two elements of the basis you can get $1,t$. From this and the third you can get $t^2$. Hence you can get anything involving $1,t,t^2,t^3$.

Comment: Thank you for catching that it seemed like I was missing something

Comment: Seems to me that once you have a list of four things, one of each degree, you’re done. Using the hint of @copper.hat , you get your constant. Stop there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can prove independence slightly more easily than solving the "bijectivity" system.

From $dt^3+c(t^2-1)+b(t+1)+a(t-1)=0\iff\begin{cases}d=0\\c=0\\a+b=0\\-a+b-c=0\end{cases}$

This is an easy solve showing  $a=b=c=d=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $a+b=\alpha_1\land b-a-c=\alpha_0\implies a+b=\alpha_1\land b-a=\alpha_0+\alpha_2\implies b=(\alpha_0+\alpha_1+\alpha_2)/2\land a=(\alpha_1-\alpha_0-\alpha_2)/2$.  So we have a basis.